# Unit test Quick and Numble - Not shown in coverage

Tags: swift, unit-testing, code-coverage, quick-nimble

I'm having a problem with some unit testing and coverage.

```
class InputFileReaderSpec: QuickSpec {

    override func spec() {

        beforeEach {

        }

        describe("InputFileReader") {
            it("should be able to read a file") {
                let inputFileReader = InputFileReader()
                let string = try? inputFileReader.readFileAt("f_digital-security-incident.yml")
                expect(string).notTo(beNil())
            }

            it("should try to read a file doesnt exist") {
                let inputFileReader = InputFileReader()
                expect {
                    try inputFileReader.readFileAt("test.yml")
                    }.to(throwError(InputFileReaderError.inputFileNotFound))

            }

            it("should try to read a file with format invalid") {
                let inputFileReader = InputFileReader()
                expect {
                    try inputFileReader.readFileAt("tool_cobian1.png")
                    }.to(throwError(InputFileReaderError.invalidFileFormat))
            }
        }

        afterEach {

        }
    }
}
```

My InputFileReader

```
import Foundation

enum InputFileReaderError: Error {
    case inputFileNotFound
    case invalidFileFormat
}

class InputFileReader {

         func readFileAt(_ fileName: String) throws -> String {
        guard let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "") else {
            throw InputFileReaderError.inputFileNotFound
        }

        guard let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            throw InputFileReaderError.invalidFileFormat
        }
        return content
    }
}
```

The problem that happens is that the coverage shows that it had no test for the code snippet, but when running it passes and is tested.

[Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVhfO.png)

Has anyone ever experienced this?
[Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSD5A.png)

Comment: Have you find any solution?